# Calling NodeJS function from JS function

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, email

I am doing a project based on firebase and I need to link a server-side function that sends an email to the client-side script.

This is my server-side index.js file

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
    user: 'xxx@gmail.com',
    pass: 'password'
  }
});

var mailOptions = {
  from: 'xxx@gmail.com',
  to: 'xxx@gmail.com',
  subject: 'Sending Email using Node.js',
  text: 'That was easy!'
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
  }
});
```

I am wondering how I could have a button in html call a function in the script that will call the transporter.sendMail. I have never touched node js before so please excuse my lack of knowledge.

If this helps firebase setup my folders to be separated by functions and public for the server-side and client-side files

[image]

Comment: You can easily make use of ajax request from your client side JS to NodeJS server to send the mail

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable

Comment: @DougStevenson ill look and try that out

Comment: @SushinPv could you expand on that and give an example of how I would do it?

Comment: Sure no problem at all. When am free I'll post the complete ans.

Answer (score -1):

> First initialize your HTML page with `jQuery` and on submitting the form send an `Ajax` request to the server as follows

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#formoid").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://xxxxxxx.com/contact', // url where to submit the request
            type : "POST", // type of action POST || GET
            dataType : 'json', // data type
            data : $("#formoid").serialize(), // post data || get data
            success : function(result) {
                $('#formoid')[0].reset();
            },
            error: function(xhr, resp, text) {
                console.log(xhr, resp, text);
            }
        })

    });
});
```

> Create a route called `contact` in your `NodeJS` server and listen for the contact request with All parameters required for your need. In the following case am using an `express server` and `body parser` to parse the data from incoming request

```
app.post('/contact', (req, res) => {
    var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: "Gmail",
        auth: {
            user: "xxxxx",
            pass: "xxxxx"
        }
    });

    var mailOptions = {
        from: req.body.email,
        to: 'xxxxx@xx.com',
        subject: 'Contact form',
        text: 'From: ' + req.body.name + '\n Email: ' + req.body.email + '\nMessage: ' + req.body.msg
    };
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
        if (error) {
            res.status(500).json({
                message: "Error",
                error: error
            })
        } else {
            res.status(200).json({
                message: "Its working",
                response: info.response
            })
        }
    });
});
```

> In the above request am sending the `name:as name`, `email: as email` and `message: as msg`